# make tf from rosbag data raw

Tags: navigation, odometry, tf2, timestamp, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to make tf tree from rosbag file and raw topics like /imu/data and /scan without tf topic. At the time when record the bagfile, we don't know the tf jet and now we want to make the tf appropriate tree.

We are doing tf static transform with static_transform_publisher nodes by launch file:

```
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_imu" args="0.5 0 0.1 0 1.57 0 /base_link /imu 10"/>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_footprint" args="0 0 0.2 0 0 0 /base_footprint /base_link 10"/>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_laser" args="0.5 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /laser 10"/>
```

In imu msg topic, the header is the follow:

```
header: 
  seq: 49958
  stamp: 
    secs: 1410520339
    nsecs: 565862711
  frame_id: imu
```

Frame_id : imu.

The same for the laser data:

```
header: 
  seq: 1831
  stamp: 
    secs: 1410520215
    nsecs: 426117012
  frame_id: laser
angle_min: -0.872664630413
angle_max: 0.872664630413
angle_increment: 0.00436332309619
time_increment: 3.70370362361e-05
scan_time: 0.0533333346248
range_min: 0.0
range_max: 81.0
```

Notice that both frame publisher are "imu" and "laser".
Now we run the launch file generating the tree but when we want to see in rviz, appear the next msg:
In imu frame:

```
Transform [sender=unknown_publisher]
Message removed because it is too old (frame=[imu], stamp=[1410520316.775747058])
```

In laser frame.

```
Transform [sender=unknown_publisher]
Message removed because it is too old (frame=[laser], stamp=[1410520194.940736519])
```

The problem is the msg has other timestamp as the tf_publisher.

What is the best strategy to make new tf with old timestamp to use the raw data from the rosbag file?
The aim is watch the robot pose and the map/odometry just with the rosbag sensors. I read hector_mapping can do the thing but need tf in order to make correct odometry.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192587/make-tf-from-rosbag-data-raw/) by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2014-09-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Set the parameter /use_sim_time to true, and use the --clock option in 'rosbag play'

This tells all nodes to use timestamps published from the bag.

http://wiki.ros.org/Clock#Using_Simulation_Time_from_the_.2BAC8-clock_Topic

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2014-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on 2014-09-12**:
Works great. Thank you very much.

**Comment by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) on 2017-08-29**:
Still same error coming up in Rviz. Is there something else. How to make Rviz understand that is the timestamp it needs to look?

**Comment by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) on 2017-08-29**:
Yeah thanks! It worked . Setting /use_sim_time before running any node

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure to set the `/use_sime_time` parameter to `true` before running Rviz. Nodes only check that parameter at startup. Also, Rviz will display 'Wall Time' and 'ROS Time' in the lower left.

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2017-08-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1